# How do I create a Minitab-style 'multi-vari' chart in R with one continuous and two factor variables?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a simple Minitab-style multivari chart in R that plots a continuous variable simultaneously as a function of two or more factor variables and can't get 'mvPlot' or 'multivari' to work in R.  Is there a suitable replacement function in R to create the following output (assumes 'diameter' is the continuous output variable and setting (=1,2,3) and machine(=1,2) are the factor variables of interest:

I tried the R function 'mvPlot' but was told that this function is not supported in my version of R (installed August 2022 on a Macbook).  I then tried using the R function 'multivari' and got the following error message: "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : recursive indexing failed and level 2"

https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/21/help-and-how-to/quality-and-process-improvement/quality-tools/how-to/multi-vari-chart/before-you-start/overview/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A bit rough and ready, but here’s a ggplot2 approximation:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

machine_data <- data.frame(
  machine = factor(rep(1:2, each = 3)),
  setting = factor(rep(1:3, 2)),
  diameter = c(4.6, 5.6, 6.9, 5.3, 4.9, 4.9)
)

machine_means <- machine_data %>%
  group_by(setting) %>%
  summarize(diameter = mean(diameter))

ggplot(machine_data, aes(setting, diameter)) +
  geom_line(
    aes(group = setting), 
    color = "blue"
  ) +
  geom_point(
    aes(shape = machine), 
    color = "blue",
    size = 4
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = machine_means, 
    aes(group = ""),
    color = "red",
    linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = machine_means, 
    color = "red",
    size = 4
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 16)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

You could also wrap this in a function to adapt to multiple plots:

```
ggmulti_vari <- function(data, x, y, group, color1 = "blue", color2 = "red") {
  data <- rename(data, x = {{x}}, y = {{y}}, grp = {{group}})

  means <- data %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    summarize(y = mean(y))

  ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line(
      aes(group = x), 
      color = color1
    ) +
    geom_point(
      aes(shape = grp), 
      color = color1,
      size = 4
    ) +
    geom_line(
      data = means, 
      aes(group = ""),
      color = color2,
      linetype = "dashed"
    ) +
    geom_point(
      data = means, 
      color = color2,
      size = 4
    ) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 16)) +
    labs(
      x = as.character(ensym(x)),
      y = as.character(ensym(y)),
      shape = as.character(ensym(group))
    ) +
    theme_classic()
}

ggmulti_vari(machine_data, setting, diameter, machine)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you Zephryl!  This is a great approach and I can't wait to try this out - I appreciate your help as it has been rough going trying to 'convert' myself from a longtime Minitab user to an R person going forward. :)